# Fill google maps viewport with single tile

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, gis, wms

Basically what I am trying to do is find a way to load ONLY one image/tile which will fill the viewport and not have any surrounding tiles loaded.  It appears this is the methodology the good folks at Weather Underground are doing w/their [Wundermap](http://www.wunderground.com/wundermap/).

I've tried digging through their code but to no avail.  I tried simply using larger tiles - larger than the actual viewport - but this has several adverse side effects.  There was a similar question asked in [WMS as a single tile image in Google Maps v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425389/wms-as-a-single-tile-image-in-google-maps-v3) but that was more about just using larger tiles than using a single tile.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

Here is a link to a page/map on their site that loads a single tile/image that spans the entire viewport:

http://wxug.us/o4ia

If you have the Net tab open in firebug you can see that there is a single tile request.  Also, if you keep it open and pan the map - while keeping the mouse down - the data does not fill in until you release the mouse.  For all the tiled maps I have seen, as soon as you pan, it starts filling in new tiles.

Comment: AFAICT Wundermap is not using one large tile. You could use the Google Static Image API and set the scale to 2X, load that as the initial map, and then load the Google Maps API as needed.  However, there is no way of limiting the number of tiles and the surrounding tiles via the Google Maps Javascript API.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I updated my post w/a new link that takes you directly to a page where they only load a single tile that fills the viewport.  Maybe I am just missing something.

Comment: They're using a custom overlay.  You'll need to set up a server-side way of serving out your own image overlays to display on Google Maps, based on the viewport (presuming you want to serve 1 image that displays over the entire viewport).  http://goo.gl/zgEKB

Comment: Brilliant!  Not quite sure how I missed that.  Thank you so much.  If you want to post that as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're using a custom overlay. You'll need to set up a server-side way of serving out your own image overlays to display on Google Maps, based on the viewport (presuming you want to serve 1 image that displays over the entire viewport). http://goo.gl/zgEKB